# How do I shape my 2D input and output correctly for a LSTM in Keras (tensorflow)? Generating an error when making input 3D and output one hot encoded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

For a class project, we have to take a 2D dataset and use a LSTM NN to make predictions. We are comparing it to a simple and DNN.

I need to reshape my data so that it works with the NN and am having trouble finding the right shapes for the input and output. I may also be setting up my NN wrong -- but it worked with another problem I was doing with 3D data.

My `x_train.shape` is `(2340, 590)` and my `y` shape is `(2340,)`.

I reshaped `x_train` to `(1, 2340, 590)`

I one hot encoded `y` -- which is called `binary_labels`

`binary_labels.shape` is `(2340,2)`

**Summarizing relevant input shapes:**

```
x_train.shape = (1, 2340, 590)

binary_labels.shape = (2340, 2)
```

**Problem:**

Running the model generates an error that the input arrays should have the same number of samples.

I tried reshaping the `binary_labels` to `(1,2340,2)` - but when running the NN I get `ValueError`:

> Empty training data.

```py
rnn_model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences = True),
        keras.layers.LSTM(590, return_sequences = True, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.LSTM(590, return_sequences = True, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.LSTM(590, return_sequences = True, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    
rnn_model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

rnn_model.fit(X_train, binary_labels, epochs=5, validation_split = 0.2)
```

I expect the model to run! Instead, I get an error message that I can't solve.

Anyone have an idea of how I can fix this?

**Relevant part of the error message:**
*`ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2340 target samples`*

**Entire Error message:**

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-224-36b1852bd7a7> in <module>
>      11           metrics=['accuracy'])
>      12 
> ---> 13 rnn_model.fit(X_train, binary_labels, epochs=5, validation_split = 0.2)
> 
> ~/Desktop/Program_Downloads/anaconda3/envs/uwdatasci420/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
> **kwargs)
>     641             `tf.data` dataset or a dataset iterator, and 'steps_per_epoch'
>     642             is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted.
> --> 643         validation_steps: Only relevant if `validation_data` is provided and
>     644             is a dataset or dataset iterator. Total number of steps (batches of
>     645             samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation
> 
> ~/Desktop/Program_Downloads/anaconda3/envs/uwdatasci420/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py
> in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, **kwargs)
> 
> ~/Desktop/Program_Downloads/anaconda3/envs/uwdatasci420/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
> batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
> extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2463     if not self.inputs:    2464 
> # We need to use `x_input` to set the model inputs.
> -> 2465     2466       # If input data is a dataset iterator in graph mode or if it is an eager    2467       # iterator and only one batch
> of samples is required, we fetch the data
> 
> ~/Desktop/Program_Downloads/anaconda3/envs/uwdatasci420/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
>     617   """
>     618   batch_count = int(len(index_array) / batch_size)
> --> 619   # to reshape we need to be cleanly divisible by batch size
>     620   # we stash extra items and reappend them after shuffling
>     621   last_batch = index_array[batch_count * batch_size:]
> 
> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as
> target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 2340 target samples
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understand well your question, here is the problem :

`x_train.shape` is `(2340, 590)` so you have 2340 samples of size (590,)
If you reshape you data like you did : `(1, 2340, 590)`, you will feed only one sample of size `(2340, 590)`, because keras model input shape is definied like that : `(Batch_size, size1, size2)`

So in order to get your model working you only need to reshape your data like that :

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1) #new shape = (2340, 590, 1)
```

Try that and tell me if it's better !

Answer (score 0):

I think wrapping your final `Dense` layer in [`keras.layers.TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) will solve the problem for you.

```py
    # ...
    keras.layers.LSTM(590, return_sequences=True, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
]
```

That is if you want to classify each time step in your series. Otherwise you probably do *not* want to return sequences in your last LSTM and only classify based on the final state of the LSTM after it sees your entire input sequence:

```py
    # ...
    keras.layers.LSTM(590, return_sequences=False, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
]
```

Judging from your target shape, it looks like you do have a classification label for each step in your time series, so I think you will want to wrap your `Dense` layer in a `TimeDistributed` layer.